# c# mysql query to If statement

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to create simple button that decides if you are admin or user.

But I cant get it to work properly. I'm connected to MySQL db but when I click button with either admin/user account (stored in db) I get:

> "you are an admin"

So I guess I have mistake somewhere but cant see where:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Server=;Database=;Uid=;Pwd=;");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT usertype FROM table1 ", cn); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("usertype", usertype.Text);
        cn.Open();
        string usertype123 = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();


        if (usertype123 == "admin")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("you are an admin");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are an user ");
        }

        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Just in passing... When copy/pasting connection strings to an internet site, you may want to omit the password.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table. If you don't add a WHERE statement to your query the database will return every row in your table and you get always the value from the first column of the first row (ExecuteScalar)

Comment: oh i havent noticed the password. I have 3 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add a WHERE statement to your sql command you will always retrieve the value from the first column of the first row returned by the database engine. You should change your code to something like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I assume you have a field named UserID as the primary key of your table1
    string sqlCmd = @"SELECT usertype FROM table1 WHERE UserID=@id";
    using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("....."))
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, cn))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = currentUserid;
         cn.Open();
         string usertype123 = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
         if (usertype123 == "admin")
         {
             MessageBox.Show("you are an admin");
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("You are an user ");
         }
     }
}
```

Now the problem is how to define the variable *currentUserId* This is something that you need to retrieve when the user logs in and conserve at the class level to reuse when needed. Notice also that connections are disposable objects and as such your need to dispose them as soon as you have finished to use them. The using statement helps to do this

Comment: Thanks! Ive created class called currentUserid1 but i dont know how to store id value in it. As far as i understand when user credentials are successfuly validated.I need to querry for that users id and sore in in that class so next form can use that. Any tips how to store it in that class?

Comment: It depends on how to you validate your user. Probably you have another piece of code that retrieves the user via account and password. This is the point where you need to get that id. I think it is better if you post a new question with the details of your problem

Comment: Created new question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070022/c-sharp-save-userid-value-in-class-after-login)